# C++ object model: calling virtual function by vptr leads to crash

Tags: c++, object

I've got this code snippet, it tries to call virtual function through an object's vptr (pointing to virtual function table) and uses object pointer to convert to p->vptr, like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C {
    virtual int f() {
        return 7;
    }
};
typedef int (*pf)();
int main() {
    C c1;
    pf *pvtable = (pf *) &c1;
    cout << (*pvtable[0])() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I used clang++14 to compile/link. On running it, programs returns 139, and no `cout` line is shown, seems it has crashed.

Why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: do you understand you're using undefined behavior? (and want to ask about specific implementation)

Comment: You can't rely on this.  a `vptr` and a virtual table are implementation details and all implementations are allowed to implement virtual call mechanics however they want.  If you want to call a virtual function, call it through the object/object pointer.

Comment: _"how to fix it?"_  `c1.f();`.  The vtable is an implementation detail, does not need to exist, and `C::f` is not of type `int (*)()`.

Comment: Why on earth would you *ever* write code like this? And expect it to work reliably even? Personally I don't see why - this is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) besides just plain weird.

Comment: Almost no doubt about the crash. 139 means segfault.

Comment: To do stuff like this, you need to be very intimate with the compiler and maintain that intimacy so that you can update your code as the compiler changes.

Comment: If ever there was an XY problem, this is it. Whatever the origin problem is you're *really* trying to solve, rest assured this isn't the way to do it. Your question should include the original problem that brought you to conclude this... thing... is a viable solution (which it isn't).

Comment: My guess would be the compiler can see that there are no virtual calls in your code so simply doesn't bother generating a vtable

Answer (score 2):

> Why it doesn't work

You are casting a pointer-to-`C` to a pointer-to-`int(*)()`.

This cast has no meaning in the C++ language and using the resulting pointer is explicitly Undefined Behavior.

> and how to fix it?

There is no reliable way.

C++ does not promise the existence of a vtable pointer in any program, and if there is one C++ does not offer any method to access it.